# Apache JS => PHP processing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to process requests to

**mysite.com/app.js?c=ClientID**

via PHP - as it would come to

**mysite.com/app.php?c=ClientID**

it means set up RewriteRule to apache.

I've tried to use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.)(js)$ app.php?src=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But I got

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
> Client sent malformed Host header

[image: There is the request]

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: That error message you receive sounds strange considering the rules you set up. Please take a look into your browsers development console and examine the request there. What headers are actually sent with the request? What is the full response? Please add those things to the question above. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the screenshoot.

Comment: Doesn't really help us, since you anonymized the things in question. Does that `HOST` header look ok for you? Then take a look into your http servers error log file for more clues. Also consider enabling rewrite logging to understand what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, fixed with - answer is down here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^app\.js$ /app.php?&%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below, assuming app.js non existing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.js $1.php [QSA,L]
```

For bad request error you can check this [article](https://serverfault.com/questions/285964/apache2-400-bad-request-with-rewrite-rules-nothing-in-error-log) and also confirm you are using right apache version for using if directive such as `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` which is only supported in apache 2.4.

Comment: @downvoter what is the reason for downvote? op clearly has flaw in rewrite rule which might be a reason for bad request error as mentioned here https://serverfault.com/questions/285964/apache2-400-bad-request-with-rewrite-rules-nothing-in-error-log.